# Overloaded function template

Tags: c++

I got 2 overloaded function templates:

```
template <class typ1, class typ2>
void szab(typ1, typ2) {cout << "2 typy" << endl;}

template <class typ1>
void szab(typ1, typ1) {cout << "1 typ" << endl;}
```

Why is there no ambiguity when I call a function like this: `szab(1, 1);` ? Isnt 2nd template a special version of first one? When I declare 2 parameters in a template it doesnt mean they HAVE TO be different types, they just CAN be. Why does a compiler choose the 2nd template then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Second one is *"the more specialized template"* and needs less "substituting" and compiler selects it as the best choice in overload resolution phase.

Per §14.5.6.2 (Partial ordering of function templates):

> Partial ordering selects which of two function templates is more
>   specialized than the other by transforming each template in turn (see
>   next paragraph) and performing template argument deduction using the
>   function type. The deduction process determines whether one of the
>   templates is more specialized than the other. If so, the more
>   specialized template is the one chosen by the partial ordering
>   process.

Comment: Other relevant paragraphs: [over.match.best]/1 (specifies that the partial ordering rules are used to determine which one of two function templates is *better* for some arguments) and [temp.over]/1 (specifies the steps from name resolution to selecting an overload).